# Why was my question downvoted and closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, close-reasons

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Why does this ASP web page not refresh data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76714246/why-asp-web-page-does-not-refresh-data)

A few minutes after posting I saw my question had been downvoted and closed. I don't get why as I exposed a technical problem I was facing to which I also sought technical answers... What did I do wrong?

Comment: The code you have provided to reproduce your problem consists of two script tags that include files that we can't see. Your post was closed as needing additional details. That seems accurate.

Comment: Starting questions with "hi" might be one reason. Another might be asking "can someone help". Generally try to formulate your post as a technical question without personal phrases.

Comment: @KevinB Thank you for your answer. Still, I don't get why people would need the files itself. As indicated, the problem is not the content of these files, but why the code I shared did not link to my files.

Comment: @JonesMKM i don't think the files are needed either. Neither is the code that was provided, but that's effectively the point. There's nothing in the question that can help one recreate the issue... I'm not even sure it's programming related.

Answer (score 10):

Not an ASP programmer, but I suppose something to do here would be to demonstrate *why* you think changing your extension to .aspx caused this issue.  Even better, giving us something explicit - like a stack trace, or error message, or *something* to go off of - would improve the question, too.

Answer (score 8):

***Please*** read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) carefully, and make sure you understand in detail both the advice being given and the rationale for it. Please also read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) for background.

> Still, I don't get why people would need the files itself. As indicated, the problem is not the content of these files, but why the code I shared did not link to my files.

Well, there's the operative question. Do **you** need the files themselves *in order to reproduce the problem*? If you replace them with blank files, or with dummies that do something trivial (like, I don't know, `console.log('Test that this code was run')` or something), *can you still demonstrate the problem* that way?

**What else** is required to demonstrate the problem? You seem to be claiming that you are using ASP.NET and SharePoint. What exactly does that entail? Do you have the same issue if you don't use those things, and instead just serve a plain HTML file referring to those JavaScript files, in as basic of a way as possible?

For that matter, what actually is your server configuration? What aspects of that configuration seem to be *relevant to causing the problem*? Did you try to figure this out, for example, by changing the configuration?

Aside from that, *did anything else unexpected actually happen*? For example, do you see error messages anywhere?

In the question:

> For the aspx, though, it is as if when it opens for the first time, it copies both code and keeps it as reference.

Are you familiar with the term *caching*? Does it seem to describe the behaviour you are seeing? If so, did you try using a search engine to try to find reports of similar problems? If not, what terms did you try using in a search engine to look up the problem? Aside from that: *specifically what happened* in your testing, that gives you this particular "as if" impression? You should be able to show a concrete example where the output is X is the code behaves as you expect it to, but the output is Y instead; *only then* give your mental model as to where the erroneous Y output could be coming from.